# maven distributionManagement outside the pom

Tags: maven, snapshot

Anyway I can move the distributionManagement part outside the pom 
I don't like the idea that my pom.xml contains server location,
Is it possible to move this or server name to settings.xml?
Thanks

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>archiva</id>
        <name>archiva Repo</name>
        <url>http://ca.server:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        <id>archiva</id>
        <name>archiva Repo</name>
        <url>http://ca.server:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can.

Longer answer: I like the idea too, because I could imagine that the application will be built and distributed on different servers. So I like the following:

- Define in the POM the dependencies to other libraries and plugins.
- Define in your Maven installation configuration (so it is dependent on the installation, not on the user using that installation) what you have sketched out in your question.
- Normally, you need a user-id and password to distribute in a Maven repository, and this is the (only) contents of it:

  ```
  <settings>
    <servers>
      <server>
        <id>archiva</id>
          <username>XXadmin-user-nameXX</username>
          <password>XXadmin-passwordXX</password>
      </server>
    </servers>
  </settings>
  ```

This should only be on the build server configured by the build manager and not known by everyone. The only thing you have to ensure is that the IDs are the same in both files.

Answer (score 3):

The best idea for this is to put such information into a parent POM (company pom) and use this instead of the settings.xml cause any body who wan't to build needs to change the settings.xml.

Comment: Thank you,Where will this parent pom reside? can it be in SVN? or it needs a share location?

Comment: In you own repository manager (Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva or what ever).

Comment: @khmarbaise  if the parent pom resides in the company repository, and the address of this company repository is specified in this pom - how would the child artifact find it?

Comment: An address of a repository should never been put into a pom file ... via repository manager and configuration in settings.xml not in POM...